# How can I do loop to a setInterval? (with array) - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, setinterval

In my code I'm trying to draw a rectangle at a time with help of a Matter.js plugin. The effect that I want, and I have is this: http://gyazo.com/0b84f082c4518c7c42a1651173e7b961
I'm getting from database how many rectangles should draw ( in variable `entradas[]` ). But I have many positions in array, which one says how many rectangles should draw. With timer "`desenha`" I draw one rectangle by one, up to entradas[].

My problem is that I can't make the loop for, when it draws all the rectangles from the first row, it draw the next rectangles from the second row, and so on.. For now it only draws the rectangles from first row.

That's the part of the code where I try to do it:

```
var li=1;
desenha=setInterval(
     function() {

           if(categoria[li]){
             entra=entradas[li];
             tex=texturas[li];
           }

           if(rects<entradas[li]){
                World.add(_world,
                    Bodies.rectangle( Math.round(Common.random(300,400)),-20,Math.round(Common.random(20,30)),Math.round(Common.random(20,30)), {
                        render: {
                         strokeStyle: '#ffffff',
                         sprite: {
                            texture: tex
                         }
                        }
                    })

            );  
            }
          }
            , 500);

contagem=setInterval( function(){
        if(rects<entradas[li]){
            rects=rects+1;

            document.getElementById("mytext").value = rects;
            rectsmoney=rects*valor[1];
            document.getElementById("mytext2").value = Math.round(rectsmoney);

       } 
       },500);

if(rects>=entradas[li]){
    rects=0;
    li++;
}
```

With help of an echo I know that it prints every row to entradas[];

Anyone can help me to make this loop works?

Comment: Can you post the entire loop? (not only code inside loop)

Comment: What does contagem do?

Comment: @plbsam `contagem` is to change values in html file at same time that `desenha` draw a rectangle.

I don't have more from this loop, the code above it was one of the tries I made. Another was: 
`for(var li=1;li<linhas;li++){

desenha=setInterval(  `
(.....)
`if(rects>=entradas[li]){
    rects=0;
    
}
}`

probably I'm doing this all wrong, but I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the setInterval functions and give them a temporary scope..
As desenha is a global variable, it will reassign desenha when looping. A better way is to keep a global array to store intervals.

```
(function(li) { desenha[li] =setInterval(
     function() {

           if(categoria[li]){
             entra=entradas[li];
             tex=texturas[li];
           }

           if(rects<entradas[li]){
                World.add(_world,
                    Bodies.rectangle( Math.round(Common.random(300,400)),-20,Math.round(Common.random(20,30)),Math.round(Common.random(20,30)), {
                        render: {
                         strokeStyle: '#ffffff',
                         sprite: {
                            texture: tex
                         }
                        }
                    })

            );  
            }
          }
            , 500);
         })(li);
```